# What should I do for the site at Salt Lake Comic Con?

Tags: discussion

[Salt Lake Comic Con](http://saltlakecomiccon.com/) granted me a press pass because of my blog writing for this site. Is there anything the community would like me to do specifically at the con? People to meet, questions to ask? Etc.

For instance:

Phantom42 suggested I throw a drink in the face of Shelly Rodriguez at [Inki-Drop](http://www.inki-drop.com/) (she's an old friend).

Sorry for the late notice, I was really hoping they would give me a press packet or something.

Comment: You could ask Kevin Sorbo why he keeps starring in such awful films. Is he greedy or is his agent just crap?

Comment: If you posted a month or two ago, SE would have sent you some stickers and swag to hand out.

Comment: @Kevin, while I did know a few weeks ago, there was originally some statements that led me to believe I would have access to celebrities for interviews and stuff, and I wanted to ask the community for questions. Unfortunately nothing like that panned out.

Comment: @Kevin - Where's my swag?

Comment: @Richard You came along [a couple years late](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1544/3267). And we haven't had any contests in quite some time.

Comment: @Kevin - Not even a pen or a mousemat. * sigh *. I'm not feeling the love

Answer (score 10):

Stand around with a placard asking people if they have amazing SFF questions to ask that they desperately need the answers to.

Post their questions.

Gather the rep.

Retire.

Comment: What's the dollar-to-rep exchange rate these days?

Comment: Official conversion rate is somewhere in the neighbourhood of 0.003 to 0.010 cents per rep point (no, i'm not being facetious. This is based on swag value estimate given for reaching certain rep levels).

Comment: @DVK - I ain't got no swag and I've got plenty of rep. What gives?

Comment: @Richard - You gotta know which Dark Alley to go to, to trade.

Comment: @DVK - Who've I gotta sleep with to get a decal sticker?

Comment: @Richard - according to Saint Luka, fishes